# Error when using __iter__ and __next__ with a Python linked list?

Tags: python, linked-list

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self

def __next(self):
    if self.head is None:
        raise StopIteration
    else:
        return self.head.next
```

Basically I attempted these implementation of the methods based on a basic example for W3 schools. It doesn't like that **iter** is returning an object type of the LinkedList.

Error:
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'LinkedList' linked list

If I try to return self.head, it doesn't like that it is a node object?

Error:
TypeError: iter() returned non-iterator of type 'Node'

I am trying to make my LinkedList iterable with a forloop, but am having a hard time.
Does anyone know the correct implentation to make a LinkedList iterable in Python? Similar questions on here do not make sense to me and the solutions don't work for my usage.

Comment: The first problem is due to a typo:  Change `__next` to `__next__` (you left off the trailing underscores from the name).  The other problem is that `__next__` just keeps returning the same thing over and over (for a non-empty list, it returns `self.head.next` repeatedly).  That won't iterate over the list in any useful way.  It needs to keep track of the last element it returned.  It would be better to create a separate iterator class, then create a new iterator when `__iter__` is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dunder method for the next item is `__next__` rather than `__next`, and you seem to be missing code that actually moves through the list as you iterate.

The normal method I use is to have a separate iterator class within the type to do the grunt work. In addition, the way you have your list set up makes the idea of an element class desirable as well (were you using a Python list, this would not be needed but, since you want an `item` and `next` "pointer", it's better as a separate class).

Let's start by creating the list class with an enclosed item class:

```
class MyList:
    # Single element in the list.

    class MyListElem:
        def __init__(self, item, link_from = None, link_to = None):
            # Set data, link from previous and to next if specified.

            self._item = item
            self._next = link_to
            if link_from is not None:
                link_from.change_link(self)

        def change_link(self, item):
            self._next = item
```

The element class has two methods, the first creating an element with links as needed. At the moment (see `MyList.add()` below), the `to` link is always `None` as we only append to the list.

Similarly, the `from` link is either `None` or the current tail, depending on whether we're adding the first or subsequent elements to the list.

These parameters are mostly here to cater for the possibility of later being able to insert at *arbitrary* places in the list.

---

Next is the iterator class, also part of the list class:

```
    # Iterator over the list.

    class MyListIter:
        def __init__(self, head):
            # Start at the head.

            self._curr = head

        def __iter__(self):
            # To iterate over the iterator rather than collection.

            return self

        def __next__(self):
            # Check more left, advance to next and return current.

            if self._curr is None:
                raise StopIteration
            ret_val = self._curr._item
            self._curr = self._curr._next
            return ret_val
```

This is relatively simple, the initialiser just sets us up so that the first call will return the head. The `__iter__` call allows you to retrieve an iterator from the collection and then iterate over that, rather than iterating directly over the collection. The difference being:

```
for iter in object:         # iterate over object
    pass
iter = object.__iter__()    # iterate over iterator
for iter2 in iter:
    pass
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204931/why-does-a-python-iterator-need-a-dunder-iter-function) for more details on why this may be necessary.

The `__next__` call is the "meat" of the iterator. It raises an exception if the iterator is finished. Otherwise it returns the current value, after advancing to the next.

---

And then the list class itself, a very simple one that only allows appending to the end, no deleting, and an iterator to process it:

```
    # The list itself.

    def __init__(self):
        # Empty list to start with.

        self._head = None
        self._tail = None

    def add(self, val):
        # Append to the end of the list.

        if self._head is None:
            self._head = self.MyListElem(val)
            self._tail = self._head
        else:
            self._tail = self.MyListElem(val, self._tail)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.MyListIter(self._head)
```

It's really that easy (well, relatively easy). The following test code shows it in action:

```
x = MyList()
x.add(12345)
x.add(42)
x.add("Hello")
x.add([1, 2, 3])
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

The output of that is, as expected:

```
12345
42
Hello
[1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I missed the extra __ at the end. This implementation will work for me. I have a very a very complicated link list that has a lot of methods, that's why I didn't post my linked list code cause it is lengthy. Thanks for simplifying things for me.

Comment: The iterator class is missing the `__iter__` method that returns `self`.  This is required for correctly coded [iterator classes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter).

Comment: @Tom, not entirely sure of the use case of iterating over an iterator but, since the rules call for it, I've added the method to do it. I may ask a question as to why it's needed however.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yes, it's not entirely clear, but the requirement is pretty well documented (iterators must define `__iter__` (which returns the iterator) and `__next__`).  Also, if you import the contents of `collections.abc`, then do `isinstance(obj, Iterator)`, that's the test it uses for `obj` being an iterator.

Comment: @paxdiablo One thing is does is allow you to iterate over a partially-consumed iterator.  For instance, `r = iter(obj)`, `next(r)`, then `list(r)` should work with an iterator.

Comment: @paxdiablo Another requirement is that an iterator continue to raise `StopIteration` once it raises it the first time, i.e. repeated calls to `__next__` are requirement to raise it indefinitely, as yours does.

Comment: @Tom, you may want to consider posting an answer over at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64204931/why-does-a-python-iterator-need-a-dunder-iter-function, the question I asked to clarify this.

Comment: @paxdiablo I don't have a deep understanding of this.  I do know that generators are iterators, e.g. functions that `yield` as well as things like `(x for x in range(5))`, and for those it's clear they won't work properly if they don't provide an `__iter__` that returns themselves.  User-defined iterator classes, on the other hand, are normally returned when `iter()` is called on a user-defined iterable class.  Usually this is done implicitly, and you never actually see the iterator, but if called manually, then the iterator is exposed.