# Why does a Python iterator need a dunder iter function?

Tags: python-3.x, iterator

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), a container that needs to be iterable should supply an `__iter__()` function to return an iterator. The iterator itself is required to follow the iterator protocol, meaning that it has to provide `__iter__()` that returns itself, and `__next__()` that provides the next item, or raises a `StopIterator` exception.

Now I understand why both of those would be required in a container that does its *own* iteration, since you have to both provide an iterator and a next item:

```
class ObjAndIter:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def __next__(self):
        # return something intelligent or raise StopIterator

for i in ObjAndIter():
    pass
```

However, in the case where the iterator is a *different* type, I can't see the use case for iterating over the iterator itself. Consider a (contrived) class that does nothing but provide an iterator to count up from a given number to some limit:

```
class MyObj:
    class MyIter:
        def __init__(self, start, end):
            self._num = start - 1
            self._end = end

        def __next__(self):
            self._num += 1
            if self._num > self._end:
                raise StopIteration
            return self._num

        #def __iter__(self): # This is apparently required but
        #    return self     #   it runs fine without it.

    def __init__(self, start, end):
        self._start = start
        self._end = end

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.MyIter(self._start, self._end)

x = MyObj(5, 10)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Now this appears to work fine with things like:

```
x = MyObj(5, 10)
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

*despite* the fact that the iterator doesn't follow the iterator protocol - it provides `__next__()` but not `__iter__()`. The `__iter__()` function is only called on the container and `__next__()` is only called on the iterator.

Now without the *iterator* `__iter__()` function, I see that you wouldn't be able to do something like:

```
x = MyObj(5, 10)
xiter = x.__iter__()
for i in xiter:
    print(i)
```

but I'm having a hard time envisaging when I would ever need to create an iterator over an iterator (rather than over a container).

So my question is this. Under what circumstances would I need to do this? Without that, there seems little point in having an iterator protocol at all, except possibly that the container must provide `__iter__()` and the iterator must provide `__next__()`.

---

As an aside, I *have* seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343327/why-does-a-python-iterator-need-an-iter-method-that-simply-returns-self), and its answers, but they seem to not cover *why* an iterator needs to be iterable. I can see quite well that it makes it easier for code to iterate over both the container *and* the iterator but this question is about *why* the latter is even necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterators needs to be iterable to support for-loops and iter().

This lead to: Why one would want to iterate over an iterator?

Because sometimes you're directly given iterators, for example an opened file or a generator function:

```
>>> def gen():
...     yield 1
...     yield 2
...
>>> it = gen()
>>> hasattr(it, '__next__')
True
```

This lead to: Why some parts of Python returns an interator instead of an iterable?

This is a way to tell the thing is "not rewindable" / "one-shot iterable". As returning an iterable would say "You can call iter() twice on it to iterate twice over it", which would be wrong.

Comment: On re-reading this answer, I'm actually impressed on the distinction made, which I didn't fully grok originally. An iterator (one-shot) is something you can iterate over and that's it. An iterable is something that can give you an iterator as many times as you desire. I'd upvote again if I could :-)